# .net C# ajax toolkit autocomplete can't work

Tags: c#, autocomplete

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Firstname, Lastname FROM [Patient] Where Firstname like @prefixText or Lastname like @prefixText2";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["healthcareConnectionString1"].ToString());
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "%" + prefixText + "%";
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "%" + prefixText + "%";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        items.SetValue(dr["Firstname"].ToString() + " " + dr["Lastname"].ToString(), i);
        i++;
    }
    return items;
}
```

In Default.aspx

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager 
        ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true">
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="199px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
        runat="server" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" ServicePath="WebService.asmx" MinimumPrefixLength="1"   UseContextKey="True">
</asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

I using the code above to do the autocomplete, but it won't work the suggested data didn't appear. Is there any problem of my code?

Comment: The ToolkitScriptManager-Element looks strange, missing the end-tag? I simply use the ScriptManager with the AjaxControlToolkit and it works just fine.

Comment: Does your SQL actually produce any data in return?  Have you tried to debug the lines where SQL got constructed and executed, and see if the culprit is SQL or the autocomplete component?

Comment: Hi, ya I got end-tag I left out <asp:ToolkitScriptManager 
            ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>

Comment: Yes my SQL need return data, I also try using static data return new String [] { "testing", "asdasd"...} something like this, also can't work

Answer (score 0):

Your AutoComplete extender control is looking fine, I havent used it although (I have used `<cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>` which works gr8 in my project).
Also,Service method is also OK..
Just Check wheter you are following proper steps to Add it's reference..

Comment: <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"%> I added this at top of the page.